# Dexlib2 not scannig code of application in Dexrewriter

Tags: android, dex, smali

I am using dexlib2 to replace static string from dex file.As a first step,I have written below piece of code to get classes in dex files:

```
        try {
        DexBackedDexFile dexFile = DexFileFactory.loadDexFile("classes.dex", 24);
        Iterator iterator = dexFile.getClasses().iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("Value: " + iterator.next() + " ");
        }

        System.out.println("done");
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Issue is it is printing out all classes other than from my code.

Anybody is facing same issue? Also to clarify, my dex file is one of dex file from multiple dex files as my app is using multidex feature.

Comment: An application's classes can be in any of the dex files in a multidex application.

Comment: @JesusFreke:  I have put dex file which has that code as I have crosschecked it by using dex2jar tool. Another point is maybe it is to do with api level I have passed for opcodes. Also my main task is to replace particular String constant. is it possible with dexlib2 Dexrewriter class?

Comment: The code that is iterating over classes is relatively straightforward, with no known bugs. If the class is in the dex file, the code you wrote will find it during iteration and print it. And yes, that is possible. Have you tried looking in the other dex files? ;)

Comment: @JesusFreke: ok. that was the issue:(

Answer (score 0):

It was issue of multi dex files. While iterating other dex files, It has able to find classes.